# fields_for for object: undefined method `input_field' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-forms, fields-for

I am trying to build a form using nested_form gem but i dont have a nested_attributes for any association to my model.

I did this code

```
<%= fields_for removed_co_applicant.loan_application_co_applicant do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :name, class: 'form-control personal-info-name personal-info-service', maxlength: 40, id: 'applicant-name' %>
<% end %>
```

but i get an error

> undefined method `input_field' for ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder

What should i do? i am confused.

Comment: `f.text_field`? [Ref LINK1](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/SimpleForm/FormBuilder:input_field), [Ref LINK2](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_field)

Comment: Just FYI the first link is for simple_form and not all the methods will work with a standard form_tag